# How do Iterate and loop through other data type parameters and returning their values? Java

Tags: java, java-11

I'm having to work with an interface class that other functions and classes inherit. But I'm having trouble iterating my interface array object with a max limit of 5 that use max_capacity int variable.

what I'm trying to do add item that uses addItem(Tangible item) function which in this case parameter item the interface object get's called with a backpack array in a different java file.

In addition all these functions use for-each statements and i'm not entirely sure why my if statements aren't ran as true the whole time. also we got another function called getItem(String name) with parameter String name where I'm not familiar with how you take Items interface object and compare them but as far I know you use one of the interface functions with getName or getDescription with no parameters inside the interface class.

also alot of my test didn't involve using max_capacity variable int at the top of backpack.java

### **Backpack.java**

```
 package main.com.adventure.player;

import main.com.adventure.world.objects.Tangible;



/**
 * Stores any Tangible item up to the MAX_CAPACITY.
 */
public class Backpack {
     private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 5;

    private final Tangible[] items = new Tangible[MAX_CAPACITY];

    /**
     * Adds an item to the backpack array only if there's an empty space in the array.
     * @param item - item to add to the backpack array.
     * @return - true if the item is added. Otherwise, false.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:Indentation")
    public boolean addItem(Tangible item) {
        //TODO Complete the function
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for (Tangible tangible: items) {
            tangible = item;
            items[i] = tangible;
            tangible.useItem(item);
            if (tangible.canUse(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }}
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks each backpack item's name to see if it matches the given name.
     * @param name - the name of the item to search for.
     * @return - the item if it exists. Otherwise, null.
     */
    public Tangible getItem(String name) {
        //TODO Complete the function
        
        for (Tangible tangible : items) {

            if (tangible.getName() == tangible.getDescription()) {
                return tangible;
            }
        }


        return null;
    }



    /**
     * Checks if the given item exists in the backpack based on the item's name, and removes the item if it's found.
     * @param item - item to remove
     * @return - true if the item was removed. Otherwise, false.
     */
    public boolean removeItem(Tangible item) {
        //TODO Complete the function
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the contents of the backpack. Before printing the contents, the following line should
     * be printed:
     *
     *          "Here are the items in your backpack:"
     *
     * Then each item should be printed with " - " before it.
     */
    public void printItems() {
        //TODO Complete the function
    }
}
```

### **Tangible.interface**

```
   package main.com.adventure.world.objects;

/**
 * Tangible is an interface that all objects that the player can interact with must implement.
 */

public interface Tangible {
    /**
     * The user-facing name of the object.
     * @return - the user-facing name string.
     */
    String getName();

    /**
     * The user-facing description that the user will see when they want to look at the object.
     * @return - a user-facing description string.
     */
    String getDescription();

    /**
     * If the item can be taken by the player or not.
     * @return - true if it can be taken. Otherwise, false.
     */
    Boolean canTake();

    /**
     * Informs if this object can be used with the given object (e.g. a key can be used with a door, but not a frog).
     * @param item - the item that this object wants to interact with.
     * @return - true if the items can interact. Otherwise, false.
     */
    Boolean canUse(Tangible item);

    /**
     * Use this item with the given item.
     * @param initiator - the item that this item will interact with.
     */
    void useItem(Tangible initiator);

    /**
     * Use the item by itself.
     */
    void use();
}
```

masterytask.java uses junit and amazon aws to use assernotnull and assert for example getItem uses key.getname which the dot object getname() function is again used in Tangible.interface that used in backpack.java and uses the string parameter in backback.java that I'm not sure how to work with in between the items interface tangible object and compare them in the backpack class.

### **masterytask.java**

```
    package com.adventure;

import main.com.adventure.GameInputProcessor;
import main.com.adventure.player.Backpack;
import main.com.adventure.player.Player;
import main.com.adventure.settings.Command;
import main.com.adventure.settings.CommandVerb;
import main.com.adventure.world.objects.keys.Key;
import main.com.adventure.world.objects.keys.KeyFactory;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MT8 {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBackpackAddRemoveItem() {
        Key key = KeyFactory.buildKey(1, "1");
        Key secondKey = KeyFactory.buildKey(2, "2");
        Backpack backpack = new Backpack();
        backpack.addItem(key);
        backpack.addItem(secondKey);
        assertNotNull(backpack.getItem(key.getName()));
        assertNotNull(backpack.getItem(secondKey.getName()));
        backpack.removeItem(key);
        backpack.removeItem(secondKey);
        assertNull(backpack.getItem(key.getName()));
        assertNull(backpack.getItem(secondKey.getName()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBackpackLimit() {
        final String invalidKey = "Invalid";
        Backpack backpack = new Backpack();
        backpack.addItem(KeyFactory.buildKey(1, "1"));
        backpack.addItem(KeyFactory.buildKey(2, "2"));
        backpack.addItem(KeyFactory.buildKey(3, "3"));
        backpack.addItem(KeyFactory.buildKey(4, "4"));
        backpack.addItem(KeyFactory.buildKey(5, "5"));
        backpack.addItem(KeyFactory.buildKey(42, invalidKey));
        backpack.printItems();
        assertFalse(outContent.toString().contains(invalidKey));
        assertTrue(outContent.toString().contains("5"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintBackpack() {
        Key key = new Key();
        Backpack backpack = new Backpack();
        backpack.addItem(key);
        backpack.printItems();
        assertTrue(outContent.toString().contains(key.getName()));
        assertTrue(outContent.toString().contains("Here are the items in your backpack"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBackpackViaPlayer() {
        Key key = KeyFactory.buildKey(1, "1");
        Key secondKey = KeyFactory.buildKey(2, "2");
        Player player = new Player();
        player.addItem(key);
        player.addItem(secondKey);
        assertNotNull(player.getItem(key.getName()));
        assertNotNull(player.getItem(secondKey.getName()));
        player.removeItem(key);
        player.removeItem(secondKey);
        assertNull(player.getItem(key.getName()));
        assertNull(player.getItem(secondKey.getName()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintItemsCommand() {
        GameInputProcessor processor = mock(GameInputProcessor.class);
        when(processor.prompt()).thenReturn("inventory");
        when(processor.getNextCommand()).thenCallRealMethod();
        Command command = processor.getNextCommand();
        assertEquals(CommandVerb.INVENTORY, command.getVerb());
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. You have not asked any question.

Comment: You must use `equals()` when you want to compare objects like `String` instances, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Your `addItem()` method and your `getItem()` method makes no sense. Why are you "using" an item in the `addItem()` method? The purpose of this method is to add a new item to the backpack, not to "use" items with other items. Why are you comparing the description of an item with the name of an item in your `getItem()` method? The `getItem()` method should return an item which matches the given name. You are not using the parameter `name` in your `getItem()` method at all.

Comment: Please review your question and make it as concise as you can. Test your codes to see which parts give you your problems and repost your questions about those parts.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:Indentation")` - What?  No!  Just fix the indentation.  Code style is about making your code readable.  If you are asking other people to read your code (e.g. by posting on StackOverflow), then it needs to be readable for them too.

Answer (score 0):

In line with what a lot of the commenters have said, I'm not quite sure what you are asking, however, I do see a few potential sources of error in this piece:

```
private final Tangible[] all = new Tangible[MAX_CAPACITY];
public boolean addItem(Tangible passed) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) 
    {
        for (Tangible iterated: all) 
        {
            iterated = passed;
            // ^this^ makes the values the same so
            // iterated.canUse(passed) will always be false
            all[i] = iterated;
            // and then also USES value before it checks if it can    
            iterated.useItem(passed);    
            if (iterated.canUse(passed))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

NOTE: "`iterated.canUse(passed) will always be false`" assumes that Objects do not use themselves.